# unable to pass string value to asp.net webapi from angular 7

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call my asp.net web api endpoint from my angular 7 application by passing a string value and getting 404 not found error. If you see below i am calling the getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds and passing the string to it. I am converting integer array to string and sending it

This is how the url looks:     http://localhost:56888/api/documentupload/detailsByIds/591006,591007

**Component**

```js
public createDocument() {
    const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map(doc => {
        return { // notice just a curly bracket, and in the same line with 'return'
            file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
            documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
            name: doc.name,
            documentDate: doc.selectedDate
        };
    });
    this.documents = { managerStrategyId: 0, documentDetails: null };
    this.documents.managerStrategyId = this.ManagerStrategyId;
    this.documents.documentDetails = documents;

    this.documentUploadService.createDocumentUpload(this.documents)
        .then((result) => {
            if (result) {
                this.documentIds.ids = Object.keys(result).map(k => result[k]);
                this.getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(this.documentIds.ids.toString());
                this.setGridOptions();
                this.setColumns();
                this.notify.success('Documents uploaded Successfully');
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While uploading the documents');
        });
}


public getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds) {
    if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
        this.Loading = true;

        this.initGrid();
        this.documentUploadService.getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.DocumentUploadDetails = data;
            this.Loading = false;

        },
            err => {
                this.Error = 'An error has occurred. Please contact BSG';
            },
            () => {
            });
    }
}
```

**Service component**

```js
getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds: string) {
    return this.mgr360CommonService.httpGet('/api/documentupload/detailsByIds/' +  documentIds );
}     

httpGet(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get( this.webApiLocation + url, httpPostOptions)
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
            return response;
        }), catchError(error => {
            this.onError(error);
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }));
}
```

**Server side**

```cs
[HttpGet]
[SkipTokenAuthorization]
public IHttpActionResult DetailsByIds(string documentIds)
{
    var viewModel = GetDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds);
    return Ok(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: How did you configure the route table in your ASP.NET project? (search `.MapHttpRoute` in your project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet, Route("DetailsByIds")]
public IHttpActionResult DetailsByIds(string documentIds)
{
     var viewModel = GetDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(documentIds);
     return Ok(viewModel);
}
```

Construct your call in the following way:

`http://localhost:56888/api/documentupload/detailsByIds?documentIds=591006,591007`